# arrayList<string> problem

Tags: c++, string

Here is the arrayList class:

```
template<class T>
class arrayList: public linearList<T> 
{

public:
    // constructor, copy constructor and destructor
    arrayList(int initialCapacity = 10);
    arrayList(const arrayList<T>&);
    ~arrayList() {
        delete[] element;
    }

void insert(int theIndex, const T& theElement);
protected:
    T* position;
}; // end of iterator class

protected:
    // additional members of arrayList
    void checkIndex(int theIndex) const;
    // throw illegalIndex if theIndex invalid
    T* element; // 1D array to hold list elements
    int arrayLength; // capacity of the 1D array
    int listSize; // number of elements in list
};
```

dict2 read the file and store the words in the arrayList. I use`rrayList<char[10]>`, but how can input these into the arrayList from file? The errors are indicated in the above main() function.

And in the main:

In the main function, it has the following.

```
arrayList<char[10]> *dict1 = new arrayList<char[10]> (1000);

int k = 0;
while (getline(fin, str)) {
    dict1->insert(k, str.c_str()); // error here
    k++;
}

reverseArray(dict2); // error here
```

***Edit***

I should use `arrayList<string>` in this case.

Comment: Your container lacks a copy assignment operator. Why are you allocating the containers themselves on the heap? The purpose of a container like this is that they can manage heap-allocated objects so that you don't have to, and dynamically allocating the containers themselves defeats that purpose. Is there a reason you are not using one of the C++ Standard Library containers, like `std::vector`? Why can you not use an `arrayList<std::string>`?

Comment: @ James: This is one of my class problems. It requires to use arrayList not vector. But I will change the dynamically allocated arrayList in the main() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `std::string` as the contained type. While that will fragment the memory a bit, it will make the code simpler, and less error prone. As it is, it will not be able to handle words that take more than 10 characters (or 9 plus the nul terminator if you want to make the words compatible with C strings), and you have to work a way of manually copying contents from the `std::string` that you read with `getline` to the array, and that will make the code a little awkward:

```
while ( getline( fin, str ) ) {
   char buffer[10];
   strncpy( buffer, str.c_str(), 10 ); // manually copy
   dict1->insert( k, buffer );
   dict2->insert( k, buffer );
   ++k;
}
```

If the container held strings instead of the fixed size character arrays, the code would be slightly simpler:

```
while ( getline( fin, str ) ) {
   dict1->insert( k, str );
   dict2->insert( k, str );
   ++k;
}
```

and much more flexible as it will be able to process this answer regardless of the length of the longest words (compatible:10, regardless:10).

Comment: at first, I use arrayList<string>, but there is compilation error. The erase methods uses stl::copy, so element +1 can not point to the second string in the arrayList, right? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem there. The erase, as implemented above should work, unless I have missed something while reading.

Answer (score 2):

Your `insert` function is declared as

```
void insert(int theIndex, const T& theElement);
```

`T` is `char[10]`, so you would need to pass it a `char[10]`, not a `const char*`.

Arrays are neither assignable nor copy constructible, so if you want your container to be able to handle them, you'll need to write code specifically for when the value type is an array:  they can't in general be handled in the same way that scalar objects are handled.

Comment: If I do not modify the insert method in the arrayList. How can I modify the code in the main function? Thank you.

Comment: @Sean:  You would need to have a `char[10]` in the `main` function that you could pass to `insert`.  That isn't an ideal solution.  Containers aren't generally designed to store arrays.

Comment: @Sean: Try using `ArrayList<std::string>` in main? `arrayList<char[10]>` just plain wouldn't work because arrays are not assignable (e.g your erase method wouldn't compile if you called it etc).

Comment: @ UncleBens: I should use arrayList<string>.